# Does Scipy Sparse use the (sparse) BLAS library?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, blas

Numpy can use one of a number of BLAS libraries (eg. ATLAS, MKL, OpenBLAS etc.).

Does the scipy.sparse matrix module support the sparse BLAS library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

searching the `scipy` `github` for `sparse BLAS` produces a few files like

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6a4460f68315f0669604054be91ceeacd606f0b6/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/zsp_blas3.c

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/6a4460f68315f0669604054be91ceeacd606f0b6/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/SuperLU/README

This `SuperLU` solver is the only place where the two are mentioned together.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Should have thought of searching github first!